# Conditional formating based on two columns

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

Thanks for your help. Excel 2010 question. I am attempting to have conditional formatting in one column that is based on information in that column but only under the case of a blank cell in an adjacent column. For example:
Column E has dates that have passed or not passed yet (if is has passed, action needs to be taken on that given file).
Column J has  text that indicates if action has been taken on that given file (date that action was taken or another note).

**I want to highlight cell in column E red: If the date in column E is today or later AND the cell in column J is blank.**

This will tell me if action has not yet been taken on this file where the take-action date has passed.

This seems like a simple formula but nothing has worked for me!

Comment: Perfect. I actually used ` =AND(B4<=TODAY(),C4="") ` This gave me a formatted cell in which the date has **passed** or is today. (Yes, I know my question asked for today or later) 
_Thank you_ @josh2205

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make a new rule for conditional formatting.

Select the rule for "Use Formula to Determine Which Cell to Format"

You can then use an "AND()" formula

> =AND(B4>=TODAY(),C4="")

In this example if both conditions are "TRUE" it will highlight the cell.

Note* You can apply this formula to a range but enter the formula you would use in the first cell.

[image]